# In Xamarin.Forms after renaming a Page I get the error "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist..."

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, initialization, file-rename

When I rename a Page (xaml-file) in Xamarin.Forms I often (if not all of the times) get an error involving the `InitializeComponent()` method.

[image: InitializeComponent();]

Why does this occur and what's the best way to fix this?
Shouldn't it be possible to rename a file without this happening?

Comment: Did you update the name change in both the XAML and .cs file? make sure both reference the same name then save and build.

Comment: I could rename the page with no error. Please try delete the bin and obj folder to clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it's a problem with **XAML code** you have to check what you delete from there
it's happened to me all the time try this

following step helped me, saving or changing the Custom build tool didn't work. In package manager console, issue the following command:
update-package -project your_pcl_project_name -reinstall

The build is successful thereafter but the intellisense error still exists. But I can live with that for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was closing the solution in VS, opening the XAML file in another editor, updating the **ContentPage/@x:Class** attribute there, and then re-opening in VS.